# How do I enable the AppArmor profile for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, apparmor

Recently there an [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/118222/htg-explains-what-apparmor-is-and-how-it-secures-your-ubuntu-system/) in about configuring FF with AppArmor.

When I ran the below command

> cat /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox | sudo apparmor_parser –a

I get the following error

> Error: Could not read profile –a: No such file or directory.

How to get rid of this error?

Also, I don’t use the FF which comes with Ubuntu, but I download latest FF and start using it. What changes to the command are required?

Comment: This: "I don’t use the FF which comes with Ubuntu". If you used the one that comes with Ubuntu, you shouldn't have a problem. Could you edit your question to include why you aren't using the supplied Firefox? Or do you mean you are using nightly builds? What do you mean by "I download **latest** FF"?

Comment: Also, can someone who knows better confirm whether "It isn’t enabled by default, as it may restrict Firefox too much and cause problems" from the link cited by OP is correct for the Firefox supplied by Ubuntu? I know that my Firefox is protected but I can't remember if I had to enable the AppArmor profile or not.

Comment: @vasa1: see answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply run this instead of using `cat:`

```
sudo apparmor_parser /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
```

`-a` or *add* is the default operation *apparmor_parser* performs.

> **Why?** the command as you tried it will work if you are logged in as root or you *recently* used `sudo`; the sudo password entry is causing the problem you experienced. In general, for pipes use this syntax:  `sudo sh -c "command1 | command2"`

---

> Note: the `/usr/bin/firefox` AppArmor profile **is disabled by default** in Ubuntu. As long as the version of Firefox you download installs in `/usr/bin` (e.g. not your home directory), the default AppArmore profile can be enabled and will work.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also clarify whether getting Firefox direct will require the user to edit the AppArmor profile whenever there's a version change in Fx? I'm using [Firefox beta](http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu) and I think that mozillateam adjusts the Apparmor profile accordingly so I don't have to do anything.

Comment: @vasa1, no, version changes do not require any changes in the profile. That's because AppArmor works based on file paths only, so as long as the executable is `/usr/bin/firefox`, the policy will be applied to it regardless of version or source.

Comment: My confusion is because when I first started off, I saw this as part of the output when I ran `sudo aa-status`: /usr/lib/firefox-**7.0.1**/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}. But now I'm seeing just this with the same command: /usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}. That's why I thought that version number was important. (My version is now Fx 14.)

Comment: @vasa1, I see, that's odd -- must have been a custom profile from somewhere (PPA/beta?), because the default is, as you indicated, ` `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}`, `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}//browser_java`, `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}//browser_openjdk`, `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}//sanitized_helper`
`

Comment: The full output of what I saw when I was on Firefox 7 (Ubuntu 11.10) is [here](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showpost.php?p=1969534&postcount=7). And I'm pretty sure it was the default profile **or** possibly that of the mozillateam because I did go back and forth between beta and stable. Anyway, the way it is now is nice.

Comment: Firefox 7, you say? Let me grab my time-machi....oh wait! :P

Comment: izx - thnx for the response. FF is installed in the HOME folder. What changes are required in the profile?

Comment: @PraveenSripati - please pastebin the contents of the folder with pastebinit. e.g. if firefox is installed in `~/myfirefox`, type `ls -lR ~/myfirefox | pastebinit` and include the resulting paste URL.
Please also don't forget to upvote and accept the answer, as necessary :)

Comment: I have upvoted. The content of the FF folder is in http://pastebin.com/UjiX5TRC.

Comment: Thanks. I will modify the default profile and pastebin it in a little while.

Comment: @PraveenSripati: please cd to `/etc/apparmor.d` and type `sudo cp usr.bin.firefox home.praveensripati.Installations.firefox.firefox`, `sudo cp usr.bin.firefox home.praveensripati.Installations.firefox.firefox-bin` followed by `sudo apparmor_parser -a home.praveensripati.Installations.firefox.firefox` and `sudo apparmor_parser -a home.praveensripati.Installations.firefox.firefox-bin`

Comment: @PraveenSripati: have you had a chance to try this yet?

Comment: `apparmor_parser: Unable to add "browser_java".  Profile already exists` error for the last command.